# Query documents with field less than or nonexistent

Tags: mongodb

I want to query all documents where `version` is less than 3 or missing altogether.

I tried

```
{
  version: [
    { $exists: false },
    { $lt: 3 }
  ]
}
```

but it doesn't return any documents. What is the meaning of my query and what would be the correct query?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_or):

```
{
    $or: [
        { version: { $exists: false } },
        { version: { $lt: 3 } }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure your query as written actually means anything (at least, anything documented).  It specifies an array, but no way to combine the elements logically (`$and`, `$or`, `$in`, etc).